# Function that returns the max element over all even columns in matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

How do you write a function that returns the maximum element among all the numbers that are in even columns of matrix1 i.e the maximum element among all elements in 0th, 2th, 4th etc. column. Precondition: matrix1 is a matrix filled with numbers with at least 1 row and 1 column.

The expected resulted is as follows:

```
 >>> maximum_among_all_even_columns([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,10,3,20,12,6,0]])
 12
```

Here's my attempted trial:

```
 ncols=len(m[0])
 nrows=len(m)
 sums=[]
 for j in range(ncols):
      col_sum=0
      for i in range(nrows):
           if i==0 or i%2 == 0:
                sums.append(m[i][j])
 maxf= max(sums)
 return maxf
```

Comment: If you want to return the max, why do you have there the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward, I don't think it requires much explanation.
The difficulty might be that we are used to iterating over lines then over columns, but here it is the other way round.

```
maxValue = matrix[0][0]
for j in range(len(matrix[0])//2) :
    for i in range(len(matrix)) :
        if matrix[i][2*j] > maxValue :
            maxValue = matrix[i][2*j]
```

**EDIT:** Changed `max` to `maxValue`, so that the `max` built-in function is not overwritten.

Comment: There is a little error. You are redefining the build-in `max()` function Don't do it, please!!!. To "recover" `max()` exec the following commands:
`del max
import __builtin__
__builtin__.max`

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,10,3,20,12,6,0]]
print max( sum(  map(list, zip(*l)[::2]) , []) )
```

Note : This can be run only in Python 2.x

### Explanation

I built this up as follows:

1. ```
   zip(*l)
   ```

   - creates tuples binding the elements column-wise: `[(1, 1), (1, 10), (1, 3), (1, 20), (1, 12), (1, 6), (1, 0)]`
2. ```
   zip(*l)[::2]
   ```

   - takes even steps in the list: `[(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 12), (1, 0)]`
3. ```
   map( list,zip(*l)[::2] )
   ```

   - converts the above tuples into lists (since we can modify lists): `[[1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 12], [1, 0]]`
4. ```
   sum(  map(list, zip(*l)[::2]) , [])
   ```

   - joins all the inner lists to single list: `[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 12, 1, 0]`
5. And finally

   ```
   max( sum(  map(list, zip(*l)[::2]) , []) )
   ```

   - highest value of that list: `12`

Comment: This is a Python 2 solution. The OP is using Python 3.

Comment: @idjaw As everybody should.

Comment: @Rightleg let people use what they want please... why not saying every one should use c++ while you are at it?

Comment: @JulienBernu Wow, sorry to have offended you. That was a joke bro, don't take it personally. I tend to trust the devs, so if they're making a newer version, I think it's better to use it over the older, especially since the newest has become a standard. But hey, Python 2 is still used, and Python 3 has not really proven itself superior, so yeah, there's no obvious reason to pick one over the other. I just regret that like half people are using Python 2 and the other half are using Python 3 when there is so little compatibility, but anyway, both are Python.

Comment: Anyway, can someone port this solution to Python 3, please? :) btw, don't work with 3 or more rows. Ex: `l = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,10,3,20,12,6,0],[1,10,3,20,22,6,0]]
print max( sum(  map(list, zip(l[0],l[1])[::2]) , []) )`
*12*

Comment: @Jose, edited to run for multiple rows...Note: tested only in Python 2.x

Comment: @Toby, thanks and good point. my bad laziness.... Now can you upvote? ;)

Comment: I 'translate' the zip solution to Python3 in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the max for the even cols:

```
import random
n = 10
m = 10
matrix = [[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]
```

Sol. 1:

```
%%timeit
max([element for row in matrix for col, element in enumerate(row) if col%2 == 0])
```

*10000 loops, best of 3: 19.3 µs per loop*

Sol. 2:

```
%%timeit
res = max([row[i] for row in matrix for i in range(0,len(row),2)])
```

*100000 loops, best of 3: 7.91 µs per loop*

Sol. 3:

```
%%timeit
res = max([element for row in matrix for element in row[::2]])
```

*100000 loops, best of 3: 4.92 µs per loop*

Sol. 4:

```
%%timeit
res = matrix[0][0]
for j in range(len(matrix[0])//2):
     for i in range(len(matrix)):
         if matrix[i][2*j] > res:
             res = matrix[i][2*j]
```

*100000 loops, best of 3: 8.28 µs per loop*

Sol. 5:

```
%%timeit
max([max(e) for e in [col for col in  zip(*matrix)][::2]])
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 4.48 µs per loop

The solution 5 (using `zip()`) is slightly better. 
Tested on Dual Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz (32 cores) and Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

**UPDATE**
Add timings...

**UPDATE 2** 
Solution slicing.

**UPDATE 3**
I add some code to generate the matrix, 'translate' the `zip()` solution to Python3 and test the solutions with matrices 10*10. I put all the solutions together.